# Can text documents and other files get packaged into C executable

Tags: c, executable, static-linking

My C application relies on some files to copy over. Will the files be contained in the executable and not as stand-alone files? Would it have to be linked statically? I am using Eclipse CDT if it matters.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Would [zipping][1] the exe and the file together and distributing the zip file be an option? 
  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29

Comment: No. I mean the text files are accessible only within the executable. And they are contained in the executable, not in the filesystem.

Comment: I see. Then, the option that appears first in mind is to create a `[static] const char * file_contents = ...` to hold that text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you can link file data into an executable.  A platform like Windows allows you to link data into an executable as a "resource" and provides APIs to access those resources (this is how icons and other objects are bound into a Windows executable). This is probably the best way to do it if your platform supports it - support for it is built right into the IDEs.

At a lower level, you might be able to use the linker to directly link a file into an executable as an addressable object:

- [Embedding binary blobs using gcc mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627004/embedding-binary-blobs-using-gcc-mingw)

And finally, if you're dealing with a more primitive system like some embedded platforms, you can run your file through something that converts it into source for C array of bytes:

- [Embed image in code, without using resource section or external images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225480/embed-image-in-code-without-using-resource-section-or-external-images)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do something special, no, the files will not be included in your executable.  Is there a reason you can't distribute the text files with your application?

If you want to bake the files into your executable, you can bake them in constant strings:

```
const char myTextFileData[] = "the text of the file goes here";
```

Of course, you'll have to preprocess your text files into C source files (remembering to properly escape quotes, backslashes, newlines, and other control characters).  Alternatively you can use a tool such as [`objcopy`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html) to convert the file data directly into an object file and then link that object file into your executable.

Answer (score 0):

No. The executable contains only the output from the compiler and linker. Any ancillary files your program requires must be packaged separately.