# Embedding resources in executable using GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, resources, embedded-resource

I'm looking for a way to easily embed any external binary data in a C/C++ application compiled by GCC.

A good example of what I'd like to do is handling shader code - I can just keep it in source files like `const char* shader = "source here";` but that's extremely impractical.

I'd like the compiler to do it for me: upon compilation (linking stage), read file "foo.bar" and link its content to my program, so that I'd be able to access the contents as binary data from the code.

Could be useful for small applications which I'd like to distribute as a single .exe file.

Does GCC support something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ with GCC: Statically add resource files to executable/library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There are a couple possibilities:

- use ld's capability to turn any file into an object ([Embedding binary blobs using gcc mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627004/embedding-binary-blobs-using-gcc-mingw)):

  ```
  ld -r -b binary -o binary.o foo.bar  # then link in binary.o
  ```
- use a `bin2c`/`bin2h` utility to turn any file into an array of bytes ([Embed image in code, without using resource section or external images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225480/embed-image-in-code-without-using-resource-section-or-external-images/225658#225658))

---

Update:  Here's a more complete example of how to use data bound into the executable using `ld -r -b binary`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// a file named foo.bar with some example text is 'imported' into 
// an object file using the following command:
//
//      ld -r -b binary -o foo.bar.o foo.bar
//
// That creates an bject file named "foo.bar.o" with the following 
// symbols:
//
//      _binary_foo_bar_start
//      _binary_foo_bar_end
//      _binary_foo_bar_size
//
// Note that the symbols are addresses (so for example, to get the 
// size value, you have to get the address of the _binary_foo_bar_size
// symbol).
//
// In my example, foo.bar is a simple text file, and this program will
// dump the contents of that file which has been linked in by specifying
// foo.bar.o as an object file input to the linker when the progrma is built

extern char _binary_foo_bar_start[];
extern char _binary_foo_bar_end[];

int main(void)
{
    printf( "address of start: %p\n", &_binary_foo_bar_start);
    printf( "address of end: %p\n", &_binary_foo_bar_end);

    for (char* p = _binary_foo_bar_start; p != _binary_foo_bar_end; ++p) {
        putchar( *p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Update 2 - Getting the resource size: I could not read the _binary_foo_bar_size correctly. At runtime, gdb shows me the right size of the text resource by using `display (unsigned int)&_binary_foo_bar_size`. But assigning this to a variable gave always a wrong value. I could solve this issue the following way:

```
unsigned int iSize =  (unsigned int)(&_binary_foo_bar_end - &_binary_foo_bar_start)
```

It is a workaround, but it works good and is not too ugly.

Comment: Shaders are not BLOB. They are normal text.

Comment: @VJo: then treat the blob as text.  You may have to do a bit of work to make sure there's a `'\0'` at the end of the text if you need it terminated like that.  Some experimenting might be in order.

Comment: Thanks, Michael; looks like what I needed, but I'm receiving `objdump: foo.o: File format not recognized` error, and a similar one when trying to link that object with my source. Any hints? I'm on Windows, using tdm-mingw 4.5.1 and my ld -v yields `GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.20.51.20100319`. I can fallback to your second suggestion, so it's just my curiosity from now on. :)

Comment: @Kos: I've posted an example bit of code that compiles and runs on my system.  I'm using the MinGW distribution from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html which has `gcc (GCC) 4.5.1`, `GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.20.1.20100303`, and `GNU objdump (GNU Binutils) 2.20.1.20100303`.  On your system, does `objdump -i` say anything about the `binary` format?

Comment: Sorry to say, but even after edit, your solution is still not good, because a shader is not a block of binary data, but a text.

Comment: @VJo: text _is_ binary. _Everything_ on a computer is binary.

Comment: @Michael, you can have a look at my environment here: http://nopaste.voric.com/paste.php?f=me4dr3 . If I use the nuwen's version of `ld` to create the `foo.bar.o` file (only that - I can use tdm's build for the rest), then everything works fine. I find it somewhat suprising that we're actually getting different results here. See: http://nopaste.voric.com/paste.php?f=95zizg

Comment: @MSalters re: "text is binary". Yes, but, ... in text the EOL may be treated differently on different systems.  Explicitly calling it binary prevents such foibles.

Comment: Your answer and this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4865249/670521) complement each other, so I'm linking back to it, to help peolpe to have more examples.

Comment: @MSalters Also, binary isn't even binary. Normally, you dedicate a piece of memory as either code or data (see: `VirtualAlloc` and `mmap`); by restricting access, you can protect applications. Also because of this I have my doubts that this solution will work in all cases; basically it compiles a blob as a code block and then the code uses it as a data block... iirc that should only work if the executable/DLL block is marked as `.text` - which basically (always) marks it as a data block.

Comment: @atlaste: What you describe is the distinction between writeable ("data") and executable ("code"). Read-only data needs neither method.

Comment: @MSalters Executables are mmapped and then executed. If you look closely, you'll see that EXECUTE, EXECUTE_READ and READONLY are different flags. If a section in a exe/dll is marked as 'code' (EXECUTE), there's no reason to mark it as 'read-only' - which is what's used here (and visa versa). The reason this works is that it's marked as '.text' data, which maps to the correct protection flags. Putting it in a '.code' should give errors. Link for flags: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx . Linux mmap can do similar things with PROT_READ and PROT_EXEC.

Comment: Can you tell `ld` which symbol name to generate for the data?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `&_binary_foo_bar_end - &_binary_foo_bar_start + 1`? The number of elements in the range `[a, b]` is `b - a + 1`.

Comment: @Calmarius has been asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169039/symbol-names-when-embedding-data-in-executable-on-linux it seems you can't, making this approach unusable in many cases.

Comment: Doing this with x86_64-w64-mingw32 on a Linux host, &_binary_foo_bar_size was correct when running my executable through wine, but wrong when the exact same executable was run on Windows 7. end - start always works through.

Comment: @jww no, the end is one past the end, the subtraction works as-is

Comment: I think size should be `_binary_foo_bar_end - _binary_foo_bar_start`, without `&`

Comment: @balping, it doesn’t matter, *(a)* and *(&a)* evaluates to the same value in C if *a* is an array.

Comment: @dened I checked it and you are right. To this day, I was convinced that `char * a` and `char a[]` are the same thing, but they are apparently not. Thank you, I learned something today.

Comment: ad Update 2: _binary_foo_bar_size and ASLR somehow don't work. `extern const uint16_t _binary_foo_bar_size[];` and then `uint16_t foo_bar_size = (uint16_t) _binary_foo_bar_size;` did the trick.

Answer (score 47):

As well as the suggestions already mentioned, under linux you can use the hex dump tool xxd, which has a feature to generate a C header file:

```
xxd -i mybinary > myheader.h
```

Comment: I think this solution is the best. It is also cross platform and cross compiler support.

Comment: This is true, but it does have one drawback - the resulting header files are **much** larger than the original binary file.  This has no impact on the final compiled result, but it can be undesirable as part of the build process.

Comment: this problem can be solved by using **precompiled header**.

Answer (score 25):

The [`.incbin` GAS directive](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Incbin.html) can be used for this task. Here is a totally free licenced library that wraps around it:

https://github.com/graphitemaster/incbin

To recap. The incbin method is like this.  You have a thing.s assembly file that you compile with gcc -c thing.s

```
      .section .rodata
    .global thing
    .type   thing, @object
    .align  4
thing:
    .incbin "meh.bin"
thing_end:
    .global thing_size
    .type   thing_size, @object
    .align  4
thing_size:
    .int    thing_end - thing
```

In your c or cpp code you can reference it with:

```
extern const char thing[];
extern const char* thing_end;
extern int thing_size;
```

So then you link the resulting .o with the rest of the compilation units.
Credit where due is to @John Ripley with his answer here: [C/C++ with GCC: Statically add resource files to executable/library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library)

But the above method is not as convenient as what incbin can give you.  To accomplish the above with incbin you don't need to write any assembler.  Just the following will do:

```
#include "incbin.h"

INCBIN(thing, "meh.bin");

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Now use thing
    printf("thing=%p\n", gThingData);
    printf("thing len=%d\n", gThingSize);   
}
```

Comment: I like this method because it allows controlling the symbol name.

Comment: The issue with this solution, with C++ at least, is that the resulting `std::span` you would construct representing your embedded data cannot be `constexpr` since it depends on `extern` symbols. That said, I do use your solution extensively.

Answer (score 19):

For C23, there now exists the preprocessor directive `#embed`, which achieves exactly what you are looking for without using external tools. See 6.10.3.1 of the C23 standard (here is a link to the most recent [working draft](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3047.pdf)). Here's [good blog post](https://thephd.dev/finally-embed-in-c23) about the history of `#embed` by one of the committee members behind this new feature.

Here is a snippet from the draft standard demonstrating its use:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
void have_you_any_wool(const unsigned char*, size_t);

int main (int, char*[]) {
    static const unsigned char baa_baa[] = {
#embed "black_sheep.ico"
    };
    
    have_you_any_wool(baa_baa, sizeof(baa_baa));
    return 0;
}
```

An equivalent directive for C++ does not exist at this time.

Comment: Surely `have_you_any_wool` and `black_sheep.ico` aren't actually the names used in the C23 standard though?

Comment: That snippet is taken verbatim from the standard. See p169 of this pdf: https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3088.pdf Surely we can allow the committee a sense of humor?

Comment: A sense of humour? Sure. This isn't humour, though. It's just one whose website's logo is a black sheep trying to self-insert all over the standard.

Answer (score 1):

If I want to embed static data into an executable, I would package it into a .lib/.a file or a header file as an array of unsigned chars. That's if you are looking for a portable approach.
I have created a command line tool that does both actually [here](https://github.com/TheOathMan/BinPack). All you have to do is list files, and pick option -l64 to output a 64bit library file along with a header that includes all pointers to each data.

You can explore more options as well.for example, this option:

```
>BinPack image.png -j -hx
```

will output the data of image.png into a header file, as hexadecimal and lines will be justified per -j option.

```
const unsigned char BP_icon[] = { 
0x89,0x50,0x4e,0x47,0x0d,0x0a,0x1a,0x0a,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0d,0x49,0x48,0x44,0x52,
0x00,0x00,0x01,0xed,0x00,0x00,0x01,0xed,0x08,0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x34,0xb4,0x26,
0xfb,0x00,0x00,0x02,0xf1,0x7a,0x54,0x58,0x74,0x52,0x61,0x77,0x20,0x70,0x72,0x6f,
0x66,0x69,0x6c,0x65,0x20,0x74,0x79,0x70,0x65,0x20,0x65,0x78,0x69,0x66,0x00,0x00,
0x78,0xda,0xed,0x96,0x5d,0x92,0xe3,0x2a,0x0c,0x85,0xdf,0x59,0xc5,0x2c,0x01,0x49,
0x08,0x89,0xe5,0x60,0x7e,0xaa,0xee,0x0e,0xee,0xf2,0xef,0x01,0x3b,0x9e,0x4e,0xba,
0xbb,0x6a,0xa6,0x66,0x5e,0x6e,0x55,0x4c,0x8c,0x88,0x0c,0x07,0xd0,0x27,0x93,0x84,
0xf1,0xef,0x3f,0x33,0xfc,0xc0,0x45,0xc5,0x52,0x48,0x6a,0x9e,0x4b,0xce,0x11,0x57,
0x2a,0xa9,0x70,0x45,0xc3,0xe3,0x79,0xd5,0x5d,0x53,0x4c,0xbb,0xde,0xd7,0xe8,0x57,
0x8b,0x9e,0xfd,0xe1,0x7e,0xc0,0xb0,0x02,0x2b,0xe7,0x03,0xcf,0xa7,0xa5,0x87,0xff,
0x1a,0xf0,0xb0,0x54,0xd1,0xd2,0x0f,0x42,0xde,0xae,0x07,0xc7,0xf3,0x83,0x92,0x4e,
0xcb,0xfe,0x22,0xc4,0xa7,0x91,0xb5,0xa2,0xd5,0xee,0x97,0x50,0xb9,0x84,0x84,0xcf,
0x07,0x74,0x09,0xd4,0x73,0x5b,0x31,0x17,0xb7,0x8f,0x5b,0x38,0xc6,0x69,0xaf}
```

Answer (score -4):

You could do this in a header file :

```
#ifndef SHADER_SRC_HPP
#define SHADER_SRC_HPP
const char* shader= "

//source

";
#endif
```

and just include that.

Other way is to read the shader file.

Comment: I think Kos wants to be able to maintain the shader source without having to worry about escaping special characters (among other possible issues).

Comment: @VJo: nope - never used a shader. I was approaching the question as embedding arbitrary data residing in external files into the program.  I can certainly accept that this might be a much better solution for shaders in particular.

Comment: A file which defines (as opposed to declares) a global variable should not be a header file but a source module. And your type is extremely inefficient. Make it `const char shader[] = "source";` instead.

Comment: @R a better way is to declare an external variable in the header, and define in the source file. This is also easy to maintain

Comment: Also, I believe C++ doesn't allow you to have multi-line string literals in other way than either opening and closing `""` quotes in each line separately or having a backslash at the end of every line. Not to mention the other benefits of having the shader available as a standalone file during development (syntax coloring, at the very least?).

Comment: @Kos You could put quotes at the beginning and end of each line, but that is hardly easier, but perhaps more clear. At least it is more clear to people familiar with compile time string literal concatenation.

Comment: Since C++11 you can use a "raw string literal", it looks like `R"*( ... multiline text ... )*"`. You can use another delimiter instead of *.