# Loading embedded textures with SOIL

Tags: c, opengl, soil

I am using this answer to embed my image in the .exe:

[Embedding resources in executable using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-exe-using-gcc)

Here are the relevant bits of my code:

```
GLuint grass_DTexture;

extern char binary_grass_D_bmp_start[];
extern char binary_grass_D_bmp_size[];

short loadTexture(char *imageData[], GLuint *texture) {
    *texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture_from_memory(imageData, sizeof(*imageData), SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    return 1;
}

loadTexture(&binary_grass_D_bmp_start, &grass_DTexture);
```

However the texture does not load and I just get a whitish grey surface.

EDIT: I know this was not my original question, however I am having difficulty using mipmaps. I modified my loadTexture function to this:
    short loadTexture(char *imageData[], GLuint *texture, int width, int height) {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glGenTextures(1, texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *texture);

```
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    *texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture_from_memory(imageData, sizeof(*imageData), SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT | SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS);

    //gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

    //glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, GL_RGBA8, width, height);
    //glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
    //glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    return 1;
}
```

This time, the exe crashes as soon as it is run. I am also greeted with the following warning, which could be the cause of this (probably missing an * or an & somewhere):

```
init.c:76:2: warning: passing argument 1 of 'loadTexture' from incompatible poin
ter type [enabled by default]
loadTexture.h:1:7: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[]'
```

I have managed to narrow the crash to the SOIL_load_OGL_texture_from_memory call.

Comment: This code also receives multiple warnings. Please could you fix these too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` defaults to `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR​`.

[Upload some mipmaps or switch to `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really steered me in the right direction. But when I try and use mipmaps, I receive a new problem. I'm new to OpenGL, and a lot of tutorials I have come across use either an outdated library like GLAUX or just use file access, and do not embed the textures.

Comment: @CHRIS: Why the `gluBuild2DMipmaps()`?  What was wrong with `SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS`?

Comment: Ah, I think I may have come across my issue. My imageData is the contents of a BMP file. Is the function SOIL_load_OGL_texture_from_memory designed to be used with raw pixel data?

Comment: I think it expects the contents of a supported image file, not raw pixels.

Comment: Hmm, well. I'm stumped then.

Comment: Note that simply loading the texture from an external file using only this one line works: *texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("image.bmp", SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y); so it's not a problem with lighting or anything else specific to my project.