# Having .c source file storing .txt information at compile-time

Tags: c, rtems

I'm using C to make some RTEMS application for a given target (a LEON processor more specifically).

When doing the various tutorials I noticed that since it isn't possible to load the simulation .txt files, the solution is to have .c source files (let's call them `inputs.c`) keeping the various 512x512 global input matrices and have them referenced as `extern` within the `main` file.

I'm trying to find information about this procedure but I haven't found it.

**My question:** In the documentation of the example they state that at some point they are going to transfer the global matrices in the `inputs.c` from the PC to the target via UART. Isn't the `inputs.c` file loaded into the LEON processor as well as all the other .c files?

Comment: Short of building a bootable image with a filesystem, see if you can use the approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-executable-using-gcc

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some information missing to completely understand which is your environment ...

But it could be that the data into the input.c is linked into a separated section (you should check the RTEMS linker file cmdlnk).
This way it won't be loaded by grmon but it will be loaded on specific command.

Or probably you do actually upload the data exactly at the same time of the executable code by doing the "load" in grmon.