# Memoize computational intense result in git repository without potential merge conflicts

Tags: git, memoization

Suppose I have the following dependency

```
foo.png -> foo.blend
foo.o   -> foo.png
foo.o   -> foo.cpp
```

where `foo.png` is going to be embedded inside `foo.o` with some GNU assembly hack https://stackoverflow.com/a/36295692/877329.

Now I want to compile `foo.cpp`, and `foo.png` is not up to date. Then, if the machine does not have any compute accelerators, or the scene is an indoor scene with some glossy materials, this will take a very long time.

One solution is to add the target `foo.png` to git so it gets pushed to the server but this may result in some false merge conflicts:

1. `foo.png` has been recompiled locally without any change in `foo.blend`. While the image will look the same, some metadata may be different (Blender saves timestamp in the tEXt chunk).
2. Then `git pull` is used to fetch the latest content
3. Now

   > `foo.png` will be overwritten by merge

The correct thing here, is to let the change state of `foo.png` follow `foo.blend`. Is it possible to establish this kind of master-slave relationship between two files, or can this problem be solved in a different way?

Comment: A typical solution would be to publish these large artifacts to an artifact server/repository (rather than trying to host them in Git).

Comment: Git LFS is designed to handle large binary files like image resources.

Comment: It should be mentioned that these images are not that large. The problem is the computational effort, not the file size.

Answer (score 3):

As [Oliver Charlesworth commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608886/memoize-computational-intense-result-in-git-repository-without-potential-merge-c#comment76204781_44608886), your best bet is perhaps to sidestep the problem entirely.  For instance, instead of the build rule: *Make `foo.png` by running blender on `foo.blend`*, use a build rule of: *Make `foo.png` by obtaining the correct version from an artifact-server (ipfs?), or if there is no such version, run blender.*

If you don't want to do that, though, read on.  (I think the end result is that you will want to do that. :-) )

There is a *theoretical* way to handle the full general case, by writing your own merge strategy.  The merge strategy would take a list of such "slaved" files and know to copy from the "more-mastery" side of a merge when there's a change on just one side, and fail when there is a change on both sides.  I'd suggest this is probably too hard, though, and there is a "dirtier" solution—for which the machinery is already there—using [*merge drivers*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver).

You can do anything you want in a merge driver, since you write it yourself.  In this particular case, it might be a good idea to treat this as "almost but not quite binary", i.e., as binary except for the changeable metadata): if the two inputs match except for metadata, merge the metadata and write a new PNG file and exit successfully.

You could even treat this more as a "slave result to the chosen or merged `foo.blend`", but there is a potential problem here (which is one part of why a fully general solution requires writing a merge *strategy*): you are not guaranteed that `foo.blend` has been merged yet, when your merge driver gets run.

You should also note that your own driver is *not* run if Git does not think there are multiple versions to merge.  Suppose, for instance, that you are merging commits *L* and *R* with merge-base commit *B*.  Git has run:

```
git diff --name-status B L
git diff --name-status B R
```

to figure out whether there are changes on one or both sides of the merge.  Suppose further that in the *B*-to-*L* leg, `foo.png` changes but `foo.blend` does not, while in the *B*-to-*R* leg, `foo.blend` changes but `foo.png` does not.  In this case, Git thinks all is well and takes the *L* version of `foo.png` and the *R* version of `foo.blend`.

(For your particular example, this case represents bad input: if `foo.blend` changed, `foo.png` should have changed as well—if nothing else, the metadata should probably have changed.  So this merely propagates bad input to bad output.)

Finally, note that only the artifact-server method solves the actual problem, because all of this combining at the Git level happens in a way that is unaware of the timestamp-based rules that `make` or similar build systems tend to use.  Git may merge (changes in both *L* and *R*) or copy (changes in just one side) `foo.blend` at time-stamp *T*, but merge or copy `foo.png` at time-stamp *T±k* for some nonzero *k*.  Some of these produce unwanted results (i.e., force a new run of blender).  You will *usually* get away with it as most of these things tend to happen within the 1-second granularity of typical file time stamps, so that *k=0*, and when *k>0* you have a chance of winning anyway.  (I believe, but have not tested, that Git runs the actual per-file merges in sorted order as a side effect of pairing files for rename detection; `blend` sorts before `png`, which means the time stamps always work in your favor.  But it's not necessarily wise to depend on it.)

Comment: But how to manage versions on the artifact server? It moves the problem from current repo to another.

Comment: @user877329: it does indeed.  You could use Git's hashing technique: hash the contents of `foo.blend` (with sha2-256 for instance) and look for that, and keep the last N (however many N is) generated ones somewhere(s). The really fancy version is the [Content Addressable Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_addressable_network); [ipfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System) is a bit different but has an existing semi-practical implementation.