# How to store c executable binary inside a c source?

Tags: c

I need to add a binary code of  one of my c program to another binary from a c program.how do I do it?
I need to add the binary content inside my c source.and use that c source to append that binary content to an existing binary.

Comment: This could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You should [edit]
 your question and explain a bit more what you are  _actually_ trying to achieve.

Comment: At the very least, it's unclear whether you need the binary as data for some processing or you want to use its functionality, therefore **link** it. Yes, edit this question please.

Comment: Your issue might not be C specific, you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix-likes (including Linux), you can use [xxd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd):

`xxd -i program`

This generates a header file with the contents of the file as a char array, embedding it in your program.

On Windows, you can embed the program as a resource. In your `.rc`, using 200 as a resource ID:

`200 RDCDATA "program.exe"`

Then in your program:

```
HANDLE resinfo = FindResource(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(200), RT_RCDATA);
HANDLE reshandle = LoadResource(instance, resinfo);
void *data = LockResource(reshandle);
DWORD datasz = SizeOfResource(instance, resinfo);
```

In either case you'll need to write out the file to some location to run it. Don't forget to set the executable bit on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it is possible to instruct the linker that the binary is a resource of the executable, so it will be included in the image.

I am also sure it is possible for the executable to access the resource and write it out, name it as an executable of the OS (Windows/Linux/Mac) and then exec it.

<sup>(A complete solution would depend on the OS)</sup>

Comment: well it's linux