# Write embedded executable binary from a C program to a file

Tags: c, linux, file

I'm trying to embed an executable binary inside an other one and then write the first binary to a file.

I successfully achieved this with a plain text file but when it comes to  writing an executable I cant make it work.

So for example I want to copy `/usr/bin/ls` to `ls2`, so here what I tried

- First: `objcopy --input binary --output elf64-x86-64 --binary-architecture i386 /usr/bin/ls lss.o`
- the C code:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  FILE *f;

  extern char _binary_lss_start;
  extern char _binary_lss_end;

  main()
      {
      f = fopen("lss", "w");
      fprintf(f, &_binary_lss_start);
      fclose(f);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Compilation: `gcc main.c lss.o`

The Code successfully compiled but when i'm trying `./a.out` nothing is written to lss.

(I'm using Arch Linux 4.18.5 and gcc 8.2.0.)

Can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding resources in executable using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4158900/608639). In the past I seem to recall using `objcpy` to do it. In your case you should use `fwrite` and not `fprintf`. The start of data is `binary_lss_start` and the length of data is `binary_lss_end - binary_lss_start + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

As @jww mentioned you should use `fwrite`.  `fprintf` is looking for a 0 terminated string at _binary_lss_start which it might encounter in the very first byte and not write anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *f;

extern char _binary_lss_start;
extern char _binary_lss_end;
int main(int c, char *v[])
{
    size_t size_to_write = &_binary_lss_end - &_binary_lss_start;

    f = fopen("lscpu2", "w");
    if (f != NULL) {
        printf("Writing %ld bytes\n", size_to_write);
        fwrite(&_binary_lss_start, 1, size_to_write, f);
        fclose(f);
    } else {
        printf("File not found [%s]\n", "lss");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i've tried but i wasnt able to make it work (compil error, seg fault, exec error..) As i alrady my c knoledge is very low, can you provide a basic exemple ?

Comment: @V1n5 I've added an example, it's untested but should work.