# How do I get the address of a C global variable through the Haskell FFI?

Tags: haskell, import, ffi, object-files

For example, in C, I have something like this declared:

```
extern char _binary_res_txt_start[];
```

It came from this command:

```
ld -r -b binary -o binary.o res.txt
```

How can I get a `Ptr` in Haskell that points there? If it were a function, I'd do something like `foreign import ccall "&exp" a_exp :: FunPtr (Double -> Double)`, but I don't think that works for variables.

Comment: Do you really need to load the data from an actual `.o` file for some reason, or is just the point that you want the data hard-baked into the executable in the end? In that case, there are better routes.

Comment: I need data from an object file

Comment: There is a way to link a function from an object file

`foreign import ccall "&exp" a_exp :: FunPtr (Double -> Double)`

but how to link a data block?

Comment: @mxvd I incorporated your comment into the question, and also tried to simplify to get to the core of it. Let me know if I interpreted everything correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreign import` syntax works for variables too, as long as you use `&`. You can then use [`peekCString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Foreign-C-String.html#v:peekCString) or [`packCString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:packCString) to read it (or [`peekCStringLen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Foreign-C-String.html#v:peekCStringLen) or [`packCStringLen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.10.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:packCStringLen) if it's not null-terminated but you know its length). Here's a full example:

```sh
printf 'foo\0bar' > res.txt
ld -r -b binary -o binary.o res.txt
```

```c
extern char _binary_res_txt_start[];
extern char _binary_res_txt_end[];
```

```hs
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.C.String
import Foreign.Ptr

foreign import ccall "&_binary_res_txt_start" txt_start :: Ptr CChar
foreign import ccall "&_binary_res_txt_end" txt_end :: Ptr CChar

main = do
  str <- peekCStringLen (txt_start, txt_end `minusPtr` txt_start)
  print str
```

```
"foo\NULbar"
```

Note that while `ld -b binary` also produces a `_binary_res_txt_size` symbol, it's no longer useful now that ASLR is a thing. See [Why doesn't a linked binary file's _size symbol work correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54844677/7509065) for details on that.

Comment: ` Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘CChar’`
where to find it?

Comment: @mxvd [`import Foreign.C.Types`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Foreign-C-Types.html#t:CChar)

Comment: `import GHC.Ptr`
`import Foreign.C.Types`
`foreign import ccall safe "static &_binary_res_txt_start" txt_start :: Ptr СChar`
`foreign import ccall safe "static &_binary_res_txt_size" txt_size :: Ptr Int`
How can I now show the text on the screen? Text in UTF-8

`putStrLn`  or `print`

how to get a string from an address?

Comment: @mxvd See the last sentence of my answer. [`peekCStringLen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Foreign-C-String.html#v:peekCStringLen) from `Foreign.C.String` can do that.

Comment: @mxvd I just added a full example.

Comment: `foreign import ccall "&_binary_res_txt_size" txt_size :: Ptr Int`

'size' is a value and not a pointer 
`foreign import ccall "_binary_res_txt_size" txt_size :: Int`

Comment: @mxvd `&size` is a pointer even if `size` isn't. And your way doesn't work.

Comment: `len <- peek txt_size  str <- peekCStringLen (txt_start, fromIntegral len)`
This code generates `Segmentation fault` at runtime

Comment: @mxvd The standard says "It should be noted that a static foreign declaration that does not import an address (i.e., where `&` is not used in the specification of the external entity) always refers to a C function, even if the Haskell type is non-functional. For example, `foreign import ccall foo :: CInt` refers to a pure C function foo with no arguments that returns an integer value."

Comment: @mxvd Try the exact code I posted without making any changes.

Comment: The object file contains a string pointer and a length (not a length pointer)

Comment: @mxvd I know it's not a pointer. Please try my exact code anyway and see what happens.

Comment: I try the exact code you posted without making any changes. This code generates Segmentation fault at runtime

Comment: @mxvd Please copy and paste the exact C declarations of `_binary_res_txt_start` and `_binary_res_txt_size` from the C code, then. I suspect they don't mean what you think they do.

Comment: the object file is generated in this way
`cat > ress.txt`  
`some text  `  
`ld -r -b binary -o binary.o res.txt`
`objdump -x binary.o`

Comment: @mxvd Okay, I see the problem now. `ld -b binary` stores the size in a really strange way. Fix coming shortly.

Comment: @mxvd You looked too soon. I just now added the fix.