# Embed luac-bytecode into C/C++ source-file

Tags: c++, lua, bytecode, luac

How do you include a lua-bytecode-string into a C/C++ file ?

```sh
$ luac -o test -s test.lua
$ cat test
LuaS�

xV(w@@A@$@&�printTestj
```

Now if you could insert this byte-string into a C/C++-file, you could actually

```
luaL_loadfile(lua, bytestring.c_str());
```

which makes it unnecessary to load `test.lua` at run-time. You would not even have to interpret `test.lua` at run-time, right?

**Update:**

The first two comments to this question were helpful for generating a bytestring so that you can include it in your C/C++ code.
[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21605198/1511417) I got this idea:

```sh
xxd -i test > test.h
```

which creates this:

```
unsigned char test[] = {
  0x1b, 0x4c, 0x75, 0x61, 0x53, 0x00, 0x19, 0x93, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a,
  0x04, 0x08, 0x04, 0x08, 0x08, 0x78, 0x56, 0x00, /* ... */, 0x00};
unsigned int test_len = 105;
```

This is great, but this will *not* work with [luaL_loadstring](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_loadstring), since

> This function uses lua_load to load the chunk in the zero-terminated string s.

Note: there are *zeros* as data in `test`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding resources in executable using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-executable-using-gcc)

Comment: lua does not need to convert the code to byte code but the bytecode still needs to be interpreted

Comment: `(luaL_loadbuffer(L, s, length_of_s, s) || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))` should do the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [luaL_loadbuffer](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_loadbuffer) instead of [luaL_loadstring](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_loadstring):

```
luaL_loadbuffer(L,test,test_len,"");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work either, since `test` contains dec.-values which are greater than `125` . See question: `unsigned char[]`. This is why it's an array of unsigned chars. The problem here is, that `luaL_loadbuffer` expects an `const signed char-Pointer`, which is interesting.

Comment: @user1511417 `luaL_loadbuffer(L,(const char*)test,test_len,"");`

Comment: This should generate a warning, which should be taken seriously.

Comment: I've just tested gotocoffee's suggestion. It works, but why? :D