# Put binary data into an array in a C program at compile time

Tags: c

I need to put some externally generated data into an array inside a C program at compile time & to guarantee the array is 64-bit aligned. Specifically I want to initialise the input pool in the Linux random(4) device with data from /dev/urandom on the machine that compiles the kernel.

I already have a program that does it by generating a C header file that declares an array of unit64_t and fills it. That works fine in my test environment, but the kernel has large complicated makefiles which I do not fully understand & I'd like to avoid messing with them any more than absolutely necessary.

The makefile changes would be smaller if I could just generate a .o file & let the linker do the rest. A method using ld(1) is given here:
[Embedding resources in executable using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-executable-using-gcc)

That method also works fine in my tests, but I have two questions:

I need 64-bit alignment and looking at the manual it is not obvious that ld(1) guarantees that, or how to force it to if it does not.

The file size seems extravagant. I have 640 bytes of data but ld(1) gives me an output file that's about 5k. So far, playing with ld(1) options has not helped.

Comment: You can use `objdump` to see what's using all that space in the output file.

Comment: @Sandy - Your question is incorrectly worded - you want to put the data in after compile time, at link time.

Answer (score 1):

> I need 64-bit alignment and looking at the manual it is not obvious that ld(1) guarantees that, or how to force it to if it does not.

Probably *it does not*. You can use the mentioned `objdump` also to see this:

```
~$ objdump -h binary.o 

binary.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .data         00000280  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
```

Here the alignment is 2<sup>0</sup> = 1 byte = 8 bit.

If you use `objcopy` instead of `ld` to generate the object file, you can specify the needed alignment:

```
~$ objcopy -Ibinary -Oelf64-x86-64 --set-section-alignment .data=8 foo.bar binary.o 
~$ objdump -h binary.o 

binary.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .data         00000280  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
```