# repack png, dll into a single .exe

Tags: c++, sdl-2

not long ago, I created a game using SDL2 and C++, I wanted to ask if there is a way to "pack" so to speak the dll and the folders full of music images etc. in a single exe (including inside the original exe of course).

if this is a silly question I just got out of college and they didn't teach me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, and it's not a silly question, since a lot of applications are embeding some assets (icons, small wav files, even shaders) into the exe. You need to generate a `.h` file that is linked into your program. The header shall contain an array of the binary data and the size of the array for ex.

```
#pragma once
char binarydata[] = {0xaa, 0xff....};
size_t binarydatasize = sizeof(binarydata)/sizeof(binarydata[0]);
```

So in prebuild step, you have to read your binary file, dump it into that generated header (you may see `binutils` for Linux or write your own script that generates C header file and when you are done, you will want to load it into your program somehow. Usually you will have

```
extern binarydata[];
extern size_t binarydatasize;
```

in your application so your loader (let's assume it accepts `void*` for data and `size_t` for size knows that those are declared somewhere int the binary, so thus you embed the binary data directly into the executable.
Also there is a good answer here too: [Embedding resources in executable using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-executable-using-gcc)