# Embeding resources into ELF files like JAR

Tags: elf

JAR can contain resources which the java classes can make use of. You can bundle up images, xml files, etc into the JAR and it can be made use of in the java application code.

Is it possible to embed resources into a custom section of an ELF file and provide programmatic access to those resources into the code ? Is there any library that automates this process ? I am working on a native application(C/C++ with cmake as the build system) for Linux where I would like to bundle the resources needed by my application into the executable file itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to embed resources into a custom section of an ELF file and provide programmatic access to those resources into the code?

Definitely.

> Is there any library that automates this process?

You could try starting [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/issues/41) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-executable-using-gcc).